# How should i manage users when moving SQLite db to MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I made a SQLite db for a food app. Now Im mkaing a website with mysql and want to have user logins etc. Here is the sqlite db:

```
Food: foodId(pk),catId(fk), foodName, calories, protein, carbohydrates, fat
Category: catId(pk), catName
Diary: entryId, foodId(fk)
```

Now i want multiple users to add their diares. Do i just create a new table called USERS and have the the USER_FK in the DIARY table? or should I create a new diary table for each user?

to this:

```
Food: foodId(pk),catId(fk), foodName, calories, protein, carbohydrates, fat
Category: catId(pk), catName
Diary: entryId, foodId(fk), userId(fk)
User: userId(pk), userName, password(???)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried my suggestion above and it worked. I created a User table and linked it to the Diary table. So each user has its unique id connected to a diary entry.

Someone can just remove this thread or mark as solved.